# Move rows to another table with update another column using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How move rows from table like this
example "Table_A"

```
no uid code name  date
1  001 abc  test1 2016-01-01
2  001 ccc  test2 2016-01-02
3  001 bbb  test3 2016-01-03
```

To "Table_B"

```
no uid code name  status date
1  001 abc  test1 w      2016-01-01
2  001 ccc  test2 w      2016-01-02
3  001 bbb  test3 w      2016-01-03
```

and move by uid where uid = '001'

where diferent is in table_b is with status. so when the row move and status autometicly set record to "w"

Comment: Have a look at [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Why would you ever need to move rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply do something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO Table_B (`no`, `uid`, `code`, `name`, `status`, `date`) 
SELECT `no`, `uid`, `code`, `name`, 'w', `date` FROM Table_A
```

As you can see, `'w'` is just set by adding a value to the select. To move by a single `uid`, just limit the select.

```
INSERT INTO Table_B (`no`, `uid`, `code`, `name`, `status`, `date`) 
SELECT `no`, `uid`, `code`, `name`, 'w', `date` FROM Table_A WHERE uid = '001'
```

Comment: You need to remove the `VALUES` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, my syntax got a bit messed up :P. Feel free to just request an edit on the post next time :)